# Перемещение элементов DOM с анимацией при сортировке массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Как сделать перемещение с анимацией элементов согласно индексам массива `[0]` и `[1]`. Вот пример перемещения:

```
$(".col1").animate({
    left: "-=60"
  }, 2500);

$(".col").animate({
    left: "+=60"
  }, 2500);
```

Здесь нужно указать не `.col` и `.col1`, а индексы из массива `[0]` и `[1]`.

Вот сам код:

```js
var arr = [
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 2,
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = 5,
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 4,
  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = 6,
]

document.getElementById("demo7").innerHTML = "МАССИВ ЧИСЕЛ : " + arr;

function Animal() {
  function moveElement(arr, from, to) {
    arr.splice(to, 0, arr.splice(from, 1)[0]);
    return arr;
  }
  if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
    document.getElementById("demo8").innerHTML = moveElement(arr, 0, 1);
  }
}

var animal = new Animal();
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="col" style="margin-top:80px;">7box
    <p id="demo" style="font-family:Arial;text-align:center;"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col1" style="margin-top:80px;">9box1
    <p id="demo1" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col2" style="margin-top:80px;">5box2
    <p id="demo2" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col3" style="margin-top:80px;">4box3
    <p id="demo3" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко:

- используйте селектор элементов, атрибуты которых начинаются с определенного слова [`[name^="value"]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
- используйте метод [`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) для фильтрации выбранных элементов.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $elements = $('[class^="col"]');

  console.log(
    'Количество выбранных элементов:', $elements.length
  );
  console.log(
    'Текст элемента с индексом 0:', $elements.eq(0).text()
  );
  console.log(
    'Текст элемента с индексом 1:', $elements.eq(1).text()
  );
});
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="col" style="margin-top:80px;">7box
    <p id="demo" style="font-family:Arial;text-align:center;"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col1" style="margin-top:80px;">9box1
    <p id="demo1" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col2" style="margin-top:80px;">5box2
    <p id="demo2" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col3" style="margin-top:80px;">4box3
    <p id="demo3" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-align:center;"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Если объединить ваши предыдущие вопросы:

- задайте всем блокам один класс, перенесите стили блоков в таблицу стилей: ваш HTML код станет чище;
- используйте "физическое" перемещение элемента по DOM, при помощи метода [`before`](https://api.jquery.com/before/), вместо изменения HTML содержимого блоков `innerHTML`;
- используйте пользовательские [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) атрибуты для сортировки элементов, вместо сравнения их индексов в коллекции;
- дождитесь окончания анимации в методе [`animate`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options), для того, чтобы запустить следующий цикл сравнения, используя хук `complete`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button[name="random"]').on('click', randomeSort);

  $('button[name="start"]').on('click', function(event) {
    console.clear();

    $('button[name="random"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('button[name="start"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    // Отсортируем элементы по `data-id`.
    bubbleSort(0, 1);
  });

  // Рандомно перемешаем блоки.
  randomeSort();
});

function bubbleSort(first, second) {
  const cols = $('.col').toArray();

  if (!cols[second]) {
    console.info('Проход закончен');

    const isComplited = cols.every(function(node, index, arr) {
      return $(node).data('id') - 1 === index
    });

    if (isComplited) {
      console.info('Сортировка простыми обменами завершена.');

      $('button[name="random"]').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('button[name="start"]').removeAttr('disabled');

      return false;
    }

    return bubbleSort(0, 1);
  }

  console.log('Сравниваем элементы с индексами:', first, second);

  if ($(cols[first]).data('id') > $(cols[second]).data('id')) {
    const duration = 288;
    const distance = $(cols[first]).outerWidth(true);

    // Окончание анимации привязываем к первому элементу.
    $(cols[first])
      .animate({
        top: -60
      }, duration)
      .animate({
        left: distance
      }, duration)
      .animate({
        top: 0
      }, {
        duration: duration,
        complete: function() {
          console.log('Анимация выполнена.');

          $(cols[second]).removeAttr('style');
          $(cols[first]).removeAttr('style');

          $(cols[first]).before($(cols[second]));

          bubbleSort(second, ++second);
        }
      });

    // Второй элемент у нас всегда двигается только влево.
    // При этом делаем задержку `delay`.
    $(cols[second])
      .delay(duration)
      .animate({
        left: -distance
      }, duration);
  } else {
    bubbleSort(second, ++second);
  }
}

function randomeSort() {
  const cols = $('.col').toArray();

  const comparing = function(a, b) {
    return Math.random() - 0.5;
  }

  const appending = function(element, index) {
    $(element).parent().append(element);
  }

  cols.sort(comparing).forEach(appending);
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 22px auto;
  padding: 88px 12px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  margin: 0 8px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

[data-id="1"] {
  color: #5bc0de;
}

[data-id="2"] {
  color: #008cba;
}

[data-id="3"] {
  color: #6610f2;
}

[data-id="4"] {
  color: #6f42c1;
}

[data-id="5"] {
  color: #e83e8c;
}

[data-id="6"] {
  color: #f04124;
}

[data-id="7"] {
  color: #fd7e14;
}

[data-id="8"] {
  color: #e99002;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col" data-id="1">Блок 1</div>
  <div class="col" data-id="2">Блок 2</div>
  <div class="col" data-id="3">Блок 3</div>
  <div class="col" data-id="4">Блок 4</div>
  <div class="col" data-id="5">Блок 5</div>
  <div class="col" data-id="6">Блок 6</div>
  <div class="col" data-id="7">Блок 7</div>
  <div class="col" data-id="8">Блок 8</div>
</div>

<button type="button" name="random">Перемешать</button>
<button type="button" name="start">Запустить</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**PS** Код без претензий на идеальность, приведен только для демонстрации вышеизложенных подходов. Разверните `На всю страницу`, так как используется вывод сообщений в консоль.

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает, но не все понятно. Посоветуйте, что можно почитать, кроме документации jq  и  js, чтобы все понять,лучше порешать задачи на данную тему. Может, среда разработки поможет и будет подсказкой?